# Problem with the plugin sfExtraWidgetsPlugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, symfony1

Hi i installed  "sfExtraWidgetsPlugin" in my symfony project in order to use the colorpicker widget.
The problem is when i add this widget in my form and i reload my page i got this error

### ProColor Error:  Prototype is not loaded. Please make sure that your page includes prototype.js before it includes procolor.js.

and the widget didn't work. Could someone help me to solve this error??

Comment: In the script colorpicker.js, I found this line:

Comment: if (typeof Prototype == 'undefined')
 alert("ProColor Error:  Prototype is not loaded. Please make sure that your page includes prototype.js before it includes procolor.js.");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the pre-requisite - Prototype JS -> http://www.prototypejs.org/

Comment: I tried to install it with the help of this tutorial librosweb.es/symfony_1_2_en/capitulo11/prototype.html but, it doesn't work. I have the same problem. PS: when i try: <?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_prototype_web_dir'); ?> I Have nothing printed

Comment: you dont need to 'install it' you need just include the .js in your head

Comment: I tried <?php use_javascript('prototype.js') ?> in my layout bit it doesn't work :(

Comment: @khelkhel ... no probs ... nice to see my answer wasn't the one that you chose as the correct one ... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get the widget to work, you need to include a framework called "Prototype.js" (something similar to jQuery): http://www.prototypejs.org/

Comment: I tried to install it with the help of this tutorial http://www.librosweb.es/symfony_1_2_en/capitulo11/prototype.html
but, it doesn't work. I have the same problem.
PS: when i try:
<?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_prototype_web_dir'); ?>
I Have nothing printed.